# How to calculate u64 modulus u8 in Rust?

Tags: rust, type-conversion, integer, modulo

I want to write a simple Rust function that takes an `u64` modulo an `u8`, and returns an `u8`:

```
fn bucket(value: u64, number_of_buckets: u8) -> u8 {
    value % number_of_buckets
}
```

However, this does not compile because of mismatching types:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:2:13
  |
2 |     value % number_of_buckets
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected u64, found u8

error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:2:5
  |
1 | fn bucket(value: u64, number_of_buckets: u8) -> u8 {
  |                                                 -- expected `u8` because of return type
2 |     value % number_of_buckets
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected u8, found u64
help: you can convert an `u64` to `u8` and panic if the converted value wouldn't fit
  |
2 |     (value % number_of_buckets).try_into().unwrap()
  |

error[E0277]: cannot mod `u64` by `u8`
 --> src/lib.rs:2:11
  |
2 |     value % number_of_buckets
  |           ^ no implementation for `u64 % u8`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::ops::Rem<u8>` is not implemented for `u64`
```

To fix it, I have to write this very ugly code:

```
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn bucket(value: u64, number_of_buckets: u8) -> u8 {
    (value % number_of_buckets as u64).try_into().unwrap()
}
```

Is there no simpler way to do this, without two explicit type conversions and two function calls? The fact that I have two write so much code for something so simple makes me suspect I am missing something obvious.

Comment: You can write `(value % number_of_buckets as u64) as u8`

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios Thanks, that is better! Must have messed something up when I tried that the first time, but clearly it works.